# What is the difference between [colleagues] and a [coworker]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[colleague](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colleague) with currently 931 [questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colleagues?sort=newest&pageSize=15)

Tag wiki excerpt:

> Questions regarding the people one works with. This includes questions about communication, teamwork, or other issues caused by ones co-workers.

---

[coworker](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coworker) with currently 209 [questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coworker?sort=newest&pageSize=15)

No tag wiki excerpt.

---

The meaning of coworker and colleague was discussed on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49472) with the top answer stating that a coworker works at the same company, a colleague either at the same company or in the same profession / industry. But judging from the answers, not everyone quite agrees and it seems to be a subtle difference only.

When glancing through the questions, the words are used interchangeably (e. g. calling them colleague / coworker and tagging it coworker / colleague). Even [colleague](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colleague)'s tag wiki excerpt contains "co-worker".

This leads to two questions:

1. Is this difference enough to warrant two distinct tags?
2. (If yes) Have the differences been taken into account by OPs?

**Are** [colleagues](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colleagues) **and** [coworker](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coworker) **synonyms?**

If not, the tag wiki excerpts should reflect that.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: Within the context of The Workplace, there is no real difference between those two terms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No one is going to know the difference, just make them synonyms.**

I think there is a subtle difference between a coworker and a colleague, but as you said, not everyone agrees on what exactly that difference is. Add that with the fact that we have a lot of non-native English speakers here, there is *no way* we would be able to get people to use them consistently, even if we think the two terms are different. I think we can save ourselves a lot of headaches by just merging the two. I don't think it's super important which term we make as the primary tag.

As [SaggingRufus points out](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/what-is-the-difference-between-colleagues-and-a-coworker/5773?noredirect=1#comment17357_5773) it probably makes more sense to have [colleague](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colleague) be the primary, since it is the broader term. Every co-worker is a colleague, but not all colleagues are co-workers.

**Update:**

I've just discovered that users can vote on synonyms and have them automatically changed. You can **[vote on this one here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/colleagues/synonyms)**.

Comment: I agree the difference is so subtle that it really would not change an answer. Based on the answer from ELL maybe make co-worker the primary as "every co-worker is a colleague, but not every colleague is a co-worker". So make the broader one the primary. Then if someone knows the difference and it actually matters, they can use the more specific.

Comment: @SaggingRufus By that logic, do you mean to make *colleague* the primary, since it is the broader term?

Comment: yep, I mixed that up.

Comment: lol it was I who suggested that synonym request months ago :o) ... was starting to worry that I couldn't vote on it